# Buck build failing for "events-logs" Gerrit plugin (jar)

Tags: gerrit, buck

I am trying to build Gerrit plugin "events-log" jar ( https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/events-log) via Buck build, but its failing with below error:

```
root@jenkins-test:~/events-log# ll
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun 29 13:25 ./
drwxrwxr-x 24 root root 4096 Jun 29 13:22 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1017 Jun 29 12:57 BUCK
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  173 Jun 29 12:57 .buckconfig
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 29 13:25 .buckd/
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jun 29 13:05 buck-out/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 29 13:27 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  146 Jun 29 12:57 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jun 29 12:57 lib/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jun 29 12:57 src/

root@jenkins-test:~/events-log# /root/buck/bin/buck build events-log:events-  
log
Using buckd.
BUILD FAILED: No build file at events-log/BUCK when resolving target
```

//events-log:events-log.

Can somebody please tell how to fix it and build the jar.

Thanks

Comment: also having trouble building this ... can't for the life of me get it to work.  have you tried either of the methods detailed here?  https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/events-log/+/stable-2.11/src/main/resources/Documentation/build.md

Answer (score 6):

I think I've finally figured it out ...

What I wound up doing is checking out Gerrit and building the events-log plugin in the Gerrit tree.

```
git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
cd gerrit
git co v2.11.2
git submodule init
git submodule update

git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/events-log plugins/events-log
buck build plugins/events-log
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks. Just a note: the plugin goes to gerrit/buck-out/gen/plugin (at least here it does :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just want `/root/buck/bin/buck build //:events-log`.  See http://buckbuild.com/concept/build_target.html

Comment: Thanks for answering first of all. I am will retest it today and will come back.

Comment: Ok, building the way described in documentation has proceed things but now the next exception is:                                                                   #### IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/events-   log/bucklets/gerrit_plugin.bucklet'  #####                                                                                                                                                       I though building this plugin would be easy like any other plugin.

Comment: That seems specific to the Gerrit project, which I'm not familiar with at all.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found `src/main/resources/Documentation/build.md`, with which I finally succeeded in building events-log:

```
git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/events-log
git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/bucklets
cd events-log
git checkout stable-2.12
ln -s ../bucklets .
ln -s bucklets/buckversion .buckversion
ln -s bucklets/watchmanconfig .watchmanconfig
buck build plugin
```

This builds `buck-out/gen/events-log.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

If the version is 2.14 or later, please use bazle to build
And I also try to build v2.13 with buck, you need to modify gerrit_plugin.bucklet which is under bucklets folder

Old content:
target_suffix = ''):
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count
    from os import path,getcwd
New content:
 target_suffix = ''):
  with allow_unsafe_import():
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count
    from os import path,getcwd

Then execute "buck build plugin

Out put:
ruhu@CCM-P700:~/tools/events-log$ buck build plugin
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1-sources.jar

Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar

Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gerrit/gerrit-plugin-api/2.13/gerrit-plugin-api-2.13.jar

Parsing buck files: finished in 1.3 sec (100%)
Creating action graph: finished in 1.6 sec (100%)
Building: finished in 03:47.3 min (100%) 19/19 jobs, 19 updated, 94.7% cache mis
  Total time: 03:50.3 min